# preg_match to extract two numbers no matter what is between them

Tags: php, regex

I have a variable which can take any form:

```
$x = "1-2";
$x = "2 to 8";
$x = "13 days to 18 days";
```

There will always be two numbers (delivery time). I want to extract them using `preg_match`.

What would the `regex` look like?

Comment: Please show some code you have tried. The code around the regex gives some context for the question and it helps to try answers. I.e. please make a [mcve]. Also at least a very basic attempt at the regex should be possible after going through any regex tutorial. I.e. please learn to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include other variations, use `preg_match_all()` and just match digits:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $x, $numbers);
print_r($numbers[0]);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! But how can I assign the values to a variable? I thought that `$numbers[1]` and `$numbers[0]` would work, but it gives an error `Undefined offset`.

Comment: Nevermind a quick google search did it for me! For the reference: `$numbers[0][0];` and `$numbers[0][1];`

Answer (score 1):

You could go for

```
(\d+)\D+(\d+)
# require 1+ digit(s)
# require 1+ non-digits
# same as above
```

And use group `$1` and `$2`. The implementation should be fairly simple in `PHP`.